# Images seem to break tag wiki?

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, tag-wiki, internet-explorer

I can't see the source of the wiki due to insufficient participation in friday events, but [the always-friday-in-iceland tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=always-friday-in-iceland&sort=info&pagesize=15) and the [waffles tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=waffles&sort=info) appear very broken. The alignment of items is shoved out of line, and the styling on tags is all weirded. I don't see it on other pages so my guess is that the images are breaking it.

In case it's just on my end, specs are IE8 on XP.

[image: the horror]

Comment: Looks fine on **Opera.** And that's all that matters.

Comment: Switch to a real browser.

Comment: @Weblog I'm working on it! Just can't at work.

Comment: @Grace: That's no excuse. I'm at work too.

Comment: Nobody is at work. Especially if there are no downvotes. @web

Comment: STFU, random. I got a lot of stuff done today, even!

Comment: Looks fine to me on Firefox 3.6.x/Windows XP (I was the one who added the Iceland pic, BTW).

Comment: Looks fine to me on the current Chrome daily, although there is now a paragraph before the first image.

Comment: Meetings are no substitute for real work. @web

Comment: @random: Like I said, I did real work today. No meetings at all! Yesterday, too. It's so nice to actually have several hours to work without interruption.

Comment: Reproduced on IE8. Looks like IE still sucks...

Comment: Looks like an IE-only issue, then. Thanks, @Shog9. Also, the paragraph didn't change anything.

Comment: @Grace: I know. Worth a shot though; there's always a possibility that IE will suck *predictably*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to some buggy markup, firefox and chrome are much more forgiving.

Interestingly it was not cause by the images but by the markup for the tag synonyms

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed not working in IE8

IE8 Normal & Compatibility Mode
[alt text http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/2121/ie8compatnowork.png](http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/2121/ie8compatnowork.png)

### Tested and Working

- Windows

  - Firefox 3.6.8
  - Google Chrome 5.0.375.86
- Linux

  - Google Chrome 6.0.472.11 dev
  - Chromium 5.0.375.99 (51029)
  - Firefox 3.6.8

Please don't label this `[status-bydesign]` just because its IE/made by Microsoft. This is a legitimate display issue that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Go to MS' bugtracker and file a CSS bug. With any luck they'll fix it on IE 10.